# Questions on implementation of message/notification light/LED

Tags: android-12, notification-led

I hope this collection of questions on Android's "notification light" are not too generic.
Also I hope it's OK to bundle them.
Anyway, here they are:

1. Is there an API to "replace" a physical notification light by an app, i.e.: make the app "forward" events directed towards the notification light (that is actually absent), also meaning that any other app controlling the notification light would be redirected?
2. Should a current phone have a notification light (assuming Google makes hardware guidelines for phones)?
   My old Huawei Android 7/8 phone had a triple LED (I guess red, green, blue) that could be controlled by apps like signal to light up in different colors (it's also used by the system as well, e.g. to indicate a low battery), but my current Oppo Android 12 AMOLED phone has none any more.
   Somehow I miss it.
3. I noticed that when the camera is in use the display "emulates" a green notification light, so I thought the notification light might be emulated to be used by other applications as well, but seemingly it isn't.
   Or is there a setting I need to enable that emulation?
   I also noticed that I can "control" the function of the non-present notification light in some apps, but it does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Recent Google Pixel phones have no notification light, I think that says it all...

Comment: OK, so it's not required (answering item #2), but the API to control it still exists.